# tablesorter resize handles are not in correct place, when table is in a "grid" element

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

See fiddle here:
http://jsbin.com/dusisi/6/edit?html,css,js,output

When I add a tablesorter table to a 'grid' view div, something odd
happens to the column 'resize' handles: they don't appear in the
correct space (between the columns).
I forced the handles to color 'red', so you can see where they are.

Any ideas why the handles are not where they should be?

If I remove the grid containers, the resize handles are placed correctly.

(I'm using Chrome, Version 64.0.3282.119 (Official Build) (64-bit))

```
$(function() {
  $("#tickettable thead").empty();
  $("#tickettable thead").append(
     " <tr >                    "
    + "  <th >Ticket #</th>     "        
    + "   <th >State</th>       "    
    + "  <th >Last Updated</th> "          
    + "  <th >Owner</th>        "  
    + "  <th >Product</th>      "   
    + "   <th >Summary</th>     "  
    + "   <th >Comment</th>     "     
    + " </tr> "
  );

  $("#tickettable").tablesorter({
    widgets: [ 'zebra', 'resizable', 'filter' ],
    theme: "blue",
    widgetOptions: {
    }

  });
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JR4Av.png)

Comment: This is indeed an issue. I'll investigate and report back as soon as I can.